# 'TypeError: 'PosixPath' object is not iterable' 'TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str'

Tags: python

I am a beginner. I am trying to iterate through a folder containing subfolders with audio files in.
At the moment I am using 'rglob'. I want to apply a function to each of the songs individually. I have found a way without a for loop or function: however I cannot figure out how to apply to all without doing this individually...

```
# # just for 1 audio file... 
data_path = files[0] 
y, sr = librosa.load(os.path.join(files[0])) 
value_1_rms = rms_function(y)
```

But when I try to apply the function to all the songs in a for loop I get this error: 'TypeError: 'PosixPath' object is not iterable' or 'TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str'...

This is my code below...

```
sr = 22050

def rms_function(y):
    rms = librosa.feature.rms(y=y)
    rms = np.transpose(rms)
    return rms
new_rms = rms_function

data_path = '/Users/rbyc/Documents/small_labelled_data'
inputdir = Path.cwd()/data_path
files = list(inputdir.rglob("*.mp3*"))

def iterate_folders(x):
    inputdir = Path.cwd()/x
    files = list(inputdir.rglob("*mp3*"))
    for i in data_path:
        new_var, sr = librosa.load(os.path.join(files[i]))
        new_rms_val = rms_function(new_var)
        print(new_rms_val)

activate = iterate_folders(data_path)
print(activate)
```

[screenshot of folder with sub-folders and mp3 files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJxyH.png)

I know this might be quite simple but I am stuck, can anyone help? with either a new approach of iterating through the folders or a solution to changing the 'PosixPath',

Let me know,

Thanks

Comment: data_path is a string, I believe that you want to iterate through the files, so: for i in files: and join(i)

Comment: hey i'm confused, can you explain? join(i) to a new empty array?

Comment: when you are iterating through files (for i in files:) every iteration assign different file name to i, so you don't have to: librosa.load(os.path.join(files[i])), you can directly point to  i, like: librosa.load(os.path.join(i)) - If you wnat to use i as index (as you did) then use enumerate in your for loop like: for i, file_name in enumerate(files)